# apache httpclient pfx file

Tags: ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using apache httpclient 4.5.3 and apache httpcore 4.4.6. I need to invoke a SOAP WS by doing a POST call

They gave to me a pfx certificate. I used it in SOAP UI by configuring SOAP UI and all works pretty good. I can invoke the WS and it gives to me a response. So the certificate is valid

Now I'm trying to configure apache httpclient in doing the same thing. Here the code I wrote:

```
KeyStore clientStore  = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"); 
InputStream instream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(keystoreName);
try {
    clientStore.load(instream, keyStorePwd.toCharArray());
} finally {
    instream.close();
}
SSLContext sslCtx = SSLContext.getDefault();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslCtx);
Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create().register("https", sslConnectionFactory).register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory()).build();
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager pcm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
HttpClientBuilder hcb = HttpClientBuilder.create();
hcb.setConnectionManager(pcm);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = hcb.build();
```

By trying this code I'm not able in invoking successfully the WS. I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't find what I'm missing

May anyone suggest to me how to proceed?

Thank you
Angelo

Answer (score 3):

I figured what I was missing. I post my solution here hoping that it can be usefull

Basically I was wrong because I didn't configure carefully the SSLContext
I had to configure it carefully.

This is what I wrote:

```
KeyStore clientStore  = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"); 
InputStream instream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(keystoreName);
try {
    clientStore.load(instream, keyStorePwd.toCharArray());
} finally {
    instream.close();
}
//Trust everybody
X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}
    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}
    @Override
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {return null;}
};
SSLContext sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
KeyManagerFactory kmfactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmfactory.init(clientStore, keyStorePwd != null ? keyStorePwd.toCharArray() : null);
KeyManager[] keymanagers = kmfactory.getKeyManagers();
sslCtx.init(keymanagers, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslCtx);
Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create().register("https", sslConnectionFactory).register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory()).build();
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager pcm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
HttpClientBuilder hcb = HttpClientBuilder.create();
hcb.setConnectionManager(pcm);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = hcb.build();
```

Now all works pretty good

Thank you

Angelo